# Firebase serve --only functions, admin.auth() locally does not work unless I manually set the key.json

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to run cloud functions locally using `firebase serve --only functions`. It works if I manually specify the key.json that is downloaded when I create a service account through firebase console here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/project-id/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk.
And then doing `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=key.json`. Why do I have to do this? Shouldn't firebase or gcloud handle this correctly? I thought credential in `functions.config().firebase` was ApplicationDefault. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials. According to that, the env variable like above is checked first, so it works if that is there. But shouldn't #2 validate me correctly?

I have gcloud for app engine so I have done `gcloud init` and `gcloud auth application-default login`.

I initialize my app in index.js

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

`firebase serve --only functions` deploys the functions fine. But when I execute one which uses this code `admin.auth().getUser(uid)...` it breaks with the following error:

> Error: An internal error has occurred. Raw server response: "{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"accessNotConfigured","message":"Access Not Configured. Google Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project 7640...50 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/overview?project=7640...50 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.","extendedHelp":"https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/overview?project=7640...50"}],"code":403,"message":"Access Not Configured. Google Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project 7640...50 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/overview?project=7640...50 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."}}

The project number doesn't correspond to my firebase project or project id/number in console.cloud.google.com

Without gcloud, I get this error

> Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: invalid_grant (Token has been expired or revoked.)". There are two likely causes: (1) your server time is not properly synced or (2) your certificate key file has been revoked. To solve (1), re-sync the time on your server. To solve (2), make sure the key ID for your key file is still present at https://console.firebase.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project. If not, generate a new key file at https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk

similar to https://github.com/urish/firebase-server/issues/81

I already have a key file generated. I've tried deleting my existing ones and making new ones, the only solution is to download this key that is generated and manually export the environment variable

Is there any other way than that?

Comment: I have this exact problem as well...

Answer (score 2):

Technically yes, but you can build your code so that it uses a local key when testing locally, and uses the service key when running on the server.

For this I set the env var `FB_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY` to the path of the json secret. When it is unset (i.e. deployed within Firebase functions), the standard init will be used.

Here is a basic example

```
if(process.env.FB_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY){
    var serviceAccount = require(process.env.FB_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY);
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseio.com`
    });
}
else{
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
}
```